# AVX and Bubble Sort

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, avx, sse3

I have to develop a bubble sort algorithm with AVX instructions with single precision numbers in input. Can anyone help me to look for the best implementation?

I did a bubble sort version for [SSE3](http://pastebin.com/EimcJdQg):

```
global sort32

sort32: start

    mov eax, [ebp+8]        ; float* x
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]       ; int n

    call    sort

    stop

    ; --------------------------------------------------
    ; Inserire qui il proprio algoritmo di ordinamento
    ; --------------------------------------------------
    ; eax = vector start address
    ; ebx = vector length
    ; --------------------------------------------------

sort:   
    mov edi, ebx    ;contatore ciclo esterno
    sub edi, 4

ciclo_esterno:
    mov esi, 0      ;contatore ciclo interno

ciclo_interno:
    movups  xmm0, [eax+esi*4]
    jmp     verifica

; controllo se l'array da 4 non è già ordinato
verifica:
    movaps  xmm4, xmm0
    shufps  xmm4, xmm4, 10010000b
    cmpleps xmm4, xmm0
    movmskps edx, xmm4
    cmp     edx,    15
    je  incremento  

    movaps  xmm1, xmm0
    movhlps xmm1, xmm0

    movaps  xmm4, xmm0  ;confronto
    minps   xmm0, xmm1
    maxps   xmm1, xmm4

    shufps  xmm1, xmm1, 11100001b   ;inverto i massimi e riconfronto

    movaps  xmm4, xmm0  ;confronto
    minps   xmm0, xmm1
    maxps   xmm1, xmm4

    movaps  xmm4, xmm0
    shufps  xmm4, xmm4, 11100001b   ; confronto la coppia dei minimi

    cmpltps xmm4, xmm0
    movmskps edx, xmm4
    cmp     edx, 2
    je  cmp_max
    shufps  xmm0, xmm0, 11100001b   ; non sono ordinati all'interno quindi scambio

cmp_max:
    movaps  xmm4, xmm1
    shufps  xmm4, xmm4, 11100001b   ; confronto la coppia dei massimi

    cmpltps xmm4, xmm1
    movmskps edx, xmm4
    cmp edx, 2
    je  unisci
    shufps  xmm1, xmm1, 11100001b   ; non sono ordinati all'interno quindi scambio

unisci:
    movlhps xmm0, xmm1
    movups  [eax+esi*4], xmm0

incremento: 
    inc esi
    cmp esi, edi
    jg aggiorna_edi
    jmp ciclo_interno

aggiorna_edi:
    dec edi
    cmp edi, 0
    jl endl
    jmp ciclo_esterno   

endl:   ret
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sorting algorithms do not generally lend themselves to SIMD implementation. You might want to consider using a [network sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) algorithm instead, which is relatively simple to implement with SIMD for small numbers of elements. For larger sorts you can use the network sort as the inner "kernel" of a larger non-SIMD sort algorithm.

Comment: But for my problem i need to implement this type of algorithm. I did the version for sse3. This is my code and it work: http://pastebin.com/EimcJdQg 
So i have to implement it using AVX

Comment: Did you *measure* the performance of your SSE code ? Was it any faster then scalar code ?

Comment: the version of sse3 at 32 bit compile 100000 random numbers in 23 sec. This version http://pastebin.com/bmQtNKrq in avx in 33 seconds. Damn. i have to improve this performance

Comment: Well bubble sort is such a poor sorting algorithm in the first place (O(n^2)) that no amount of code optimisation will make up for this. You really ought to look at better sorting algorithms (see suggestions above).

Comment: i know this, but i have to do this for a little project and we have to implement this algorithm in the best way. So any help for my code? many thanks

Comment: If you can use SSSE3/SSE4 then you can make your existing SSE code a bit more efficient. For AVX/AVX2 the code will be very similar, but with double width vectors.

Comment: Using shuffle commands?

Comment: Yes - also look at the permute instructions.

Comment: THanks for answers. the problem is that I can't find a better solution even in SSE3. I'm using the instructions shuffle in both versions (SSE3 and AVX) and I think that in order to improve the algorithm (in AVX) I need to know how to implement a comparison of the numbers in a vector. Let me explain. in a vector AVX there are 8 single-precision elements.  my code works with 4 elements at time because I dont know how to work directly with all 8 numbers. Do you have any idea?

Comment: SSSE3 (not SSE3) has `PSHUFB` (`_mm_shuffle_epi8`) which might be useful and could reduce the number of branches.

Comment: For AVX (can you also assume AVX2, i.e. Haswell ?) you can do much the same thing - for most instructions the 8 elements are actually 2 x 4 element "lanes".

Comment: So Which permute operation can I use for resolving the sorting problem in a YMM register?

Comment: You will want to use one of the few which works across lanes, e.g. `_mm256_permutevar8x32_ps` (`VPERMPS`), but note that this is AVX2 only (which is why I asked earlier whether you are limited to AVX only or whether you can assume AVX2, i.e. Haswell ?).

Comment: I can't use AVX2. :/ but i try to focalize my problem. my code is based on comparisons, I put the 2 high elements of ymm0 in the low ymm1, then i put the max in ymm1 and min in ymm0 the problem is to put ymm0 elements in ymm1 because with SSE I have the `movhlps` that doesn't work in the same way in AVX so I have to use `vshufps` that is heavier.
so how can I use permute operations?

Comment: You're going to have a lot of problems doing this efficiently with AVX only. All I can suggest is that you implement your current SSE routine treating each half of the YMM register separately, i.e. process 2 x 128 bit vectors at once using the same approach as for SSE. The branches could be a problem though, so you'll end up with some redundancy.